# What is the accepted process for hooking into the 'Completed' event on animations using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hooking into it using code behind is trivial, but I can't work out a good way of handling it using MVVM.

Comment: You don't.  Animations is a UI concern, and therefore should belong in the codebehind, not in your view models.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my question.

You can use Interaction.Triggers.

```
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Completed">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CompletedCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method I can think at the back of my mind now is, other than putting an EventTrigger for storyboard animation, you should also put up a DataTrigger. The DataTrigger should trigger on the same Property being animated, and the trigger value should be the value when the animation completes. If this control is your own custom control (or UserControl), you can create a new dependency property `HasCompletedAnimation` on it, and bind it to the ViewModel. If the control is neither a custom control nor UserControl, you can try using that control's `Tag` property.